# Linq OrderBy - make sure an object meeting certain conditions is always first

Tags: linq, sql-order-by

I have a collection of objects, let's imagine they're strings:

```
string[] strings = new[]{"ABC", "AAA", "ADA", "DDB", "OEO"};
```

I need to perform processing on these, thus:

```
foreach(string s in strings)
{
    //do some stuff here
}
```

but I must always be sure that the processing of these, in this example, uses the "ABC" string first.

Note that although there might be a hundred strings in the list, they will always be unique, so there will never be two "ABC" entries.

I've tried various permutations of using the OrderBy() extension, thus far unsuccesfully.

Any help greatly appreciated.

---

Edit after Daniel's comment:

I'm really an idiot. What I did worked fine, except I did OrderBy when I needed OrderBy Descending().

```
foreach(string s in strings.OrderByDescending(s => s.Contains("ABC")))
{
    //do things
}
```

And this does exactly what I want.

Sorry for the waste of a thread. Would be happy to hear improvements though if any can be made.

Comment: What is the problem with what you have tried? Doesn't it compile? Does it give an exception? Is the sorting not what you wanted it to be? Please show some code...

Comment: Is processing ABC first the only requirement?

Comment: do you always know which element you want first or is it chosen by some criteria the user cant change?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

> strings.OrderBy(o=>o=="ABC").ThenBy(o=>o);

This will order by the special string, then sort alphabetically.